# Integrable function and non-continuity

Tags: real-analysis

True or false

- Every riemann Integrable  function is continuous

My answer false:
And i give the doctor this function to justify my answer

$f(x)=0$ if $x\ \in [-1,0)$
And $1$ if $x\ \in [0,3] $

And i say $f(x)$ is a fixed function so integrable but it not continuous, and he say no it is not fixed it is pointwise fixed.

So i want any riemann Integrable function and not continuous?

"I am not sure if this function has a name"

Comment: What is a "fixed function" and a "pointwise fixed function"?

Comment: I don't know its name in english i use google translate, maybe constant function? Not Increasing and not Decreasing , $f(x)=c$

Comment: A continuous function defined on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable, but Riemann integrable functions need not be continuous. Your function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Mathaholic: I guess by "fixed" OP means a constant function. But in that sense it is ideally a piecewise constant function. The proper name for such functions is "step functions". And these functions are perhaps the simplest examples of discontinuous Riemann integrable functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly fine example of a function that is not continuous but is integrable. In fact, any function with a finite number of discontinuities will be integrable. Eventually you will learn that even this is too strong, and being continuous except for on a set of measure zero is sufficient. A classic example right on the "border" of this definition:

$f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ elsewhere.  This function is not Riemann integrable.

However the function
$f(x)=1$ if $x=\frac{1}{q}$ in lowest terms, and $0$ elsewhere is integrable.

edit: With the language barrier I think the best I can do is offer a less trivial example of a discontinuous function that is integrable.

Comment: I think you want $f(x) = \frac{1}{q}$ there.

Comment: Oops was thinking about the proof with a sequence of primes

Answer (score 0):

There is another really simple example: $f(x) = 1$ if $x \ne 1$, $f(1) = 0$. It is Riemann integrable on $[0, 2]$, but has the discontinuity point at 1. (Actually you can take any enumerable number of discontinuity points and "throw them off" with the same result).